KQL Query Formatting/Prettify Library
I am running a Django web app and would like to show some KQL query to the user. However, the query is in a single line, and I would like to format/prettify/lint it. How can it be done? Do I really have to run a separate server running Node.js that than can prettify the code? Can I use the js files in @kusto/monaco-kusto or @kusto/language-service-next to prettify and syntax highlight the KQL queries on my web app?

You can use either @kusto/language-service-next or @kusto/monaco-kusto to prettify and syntax highlight KQL in your Django web app and you do not need a separate Node.js server for this purpose, as both libraries are JavaScript-based and can be run directly in the browser.

Could you please provide a code snippet or the function names I need to use? There are no documentation or examples for these packages.
